# GTest EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ fails on floating point error

Tags: c++, floating-point, googletest

I tried to use google test framework and can't see why the following code:

```
TEST(MathTest, BelowZeroCandF)
{
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(convertCtoF(-1), 30.2);
}
```

where

```
double convertCtoF(double c)
{
    return 32+1.8*c;
}
```

fails:

```
Failure
Value of: -30.20
  Actual: -30.199999999999999
Expected: tc.convertCtoF(-1)
Which is: 30.199999999999999
[  FAILED  ] MathTest.belowZeroCaboveZeroF (1 ms)
```

I know I could use EXPECT_NEAR, but don't see why the above does not work...

Comment: Are you sure you typed 30.2 instead of -30.2?

Comment: Ah true, haven't noticed the type - and that was the reason for the test failing. Many thanks!

Comment: You should accept the answer that fixed your problem. It's that green checkmark under the score.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Adding the answer to  complete the post, as OP confirmed the error in the comment.)

As shown in the error report, OP accidentally added a minus sign to the result, which is surely wrong. Removing the typo solved the problem.

Also, in GTest and many other unit testing frameworks (JUnit, etc.), the parameter order of the assertion is

```
EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(30.2, convertCtoF(-1));
//               ^     ^ actual value
//               expected value
```

otherwise the error report will have the input description flipped, just like what OP demonstrated.